# How to view the size of an InnoDB table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, innodb

When I say view the size, I'm looking to compare relative sizes of different InnoDB tables on disk.

Answer (score 0):

If you have phpMyAdmin you can easily see it there.

Comment: Thanks Denis, but I don't have phpMyAdmin. Ideally I would like an SQL command which I can type into the MySQL command-line tool (client).